# Best way to render a newsticker in HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, css-animations

We have a ticker in the bottom of an HTML page that shows news, just like a news ticker on TV. We currently use `requestAnimationFrame` for this but we experience that it does not always animate well and I wonder if anyone knows what would be the best practice for this.

Firstly, we tried running it on a Raspberry Pi and it couldn't render it well no matter what we tried.

Secondly, we are running it in a Windows PC in a Chrome browser and generally it works well, but if we play a high resolution video on the same page, then the rendering of the ticker becomes really laggy.

I understand that it's competing for resources but animating a ticker should in principle not require many resources so I think there should be a solution for this.

Here is our current code. It's typescript and not plain javascript, but my question is not so much about troubleshooting details in my current code but more about finding the best approach which I assume is something different than what we are doing now:

```
  private startTicker() {
    const ticker = document.getElementById(`RssTickerContainer_${this.props.rssTicker?.rssTicker?.url}`);
    if (!ticker || !this.state.items || this.state.items.length === 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.props.rssTicker?.rssTicker?.url) {
          // try to fetch rss content again after 1 second
          this.getRssFeed(this.props.rssTicker?.rssTicker?.url, true);
        }
      }, 1000);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Starting RSS ticker");
    const startPosition = this.state.leftPosition;
    let leftPosition = startPosition;
    let lastFrameCalled = performance.now();
    let fps = 0;
    this.animationFrameID = requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animateTicker(lastFrameCalled, fps, startPosition, leftPosition, ticker));
  }

  private animateTicker(lastFrameCalled: number, fps: number, startPosition: number, leftPosition: number, ticker: HTMLElement) {
    // calculate fps
    const timeSinceLastFrame = (performance.now() - lastFrameCalled) / 1000;
    lastFrameCalled = performance.now();
    fps = 1 / timeSinceLastFrame;
    const containerWidth = ticker.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    if (containerWidth <= 0) {
      // no content, component probably has unmounted
      return;
    }
    if ((leftPosition * -1) > containerWidth) {
      // when leftPosition (inversed, since has negative value) is greater than containerWidth,
      // this means that all elements has passed the screen so we restart the ticker
      console.log("Restarting RSS ticker");
      leftPosition = startPosition;
      ticker.style.left = leftPosition + "px";
      this.getRssFeed(this.props.rssTicker?.rssTicker?.url);
    } else {
      const timeToCross = 25;
      // use fps to set the new position to avoid slow animations on weaker devices
      const step = window.innerWidth / timeToCross / fps;
      leftPosition = leftPosition - step;
      ticker.style.left = leftPosition + "px";
    }
    this.animationFrameID = requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animateTicker(lastFrameCalled, fps, startPosition, leftPosition, ticker));
  }
```

Comment: For others that might find this question, I wanted to let you know that we did not find a better a way and I actually think that using "requestAnimationFrame" as we do in the example above is probably the best way.